# subclassed uitableviewcell subview color

Tags: uitableview, swift

I got a strange issue (in my opinion;)) considering a subclass of uitableview cell. The code for my subclass is:

```
class SubLevelTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var subLevelLabel:UILabel
    var subLevelBack:UIView
    var subLevelScore:UIImageView

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
    {
        self.subLevelBack = UIView()
        self.subLevelLabel = UILabel()
        self.subLevelScore = UIImageView()

        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.subLevelLabel.textColor = whiteColor

        self.subLevelLabel.font = UIFont(name: subLevelLabel.font.fontName, size: 20)

        self.addSubview(self.subLevelBack)
        self.subLevelBack.addSubview(self.subLevelLabel)
        self.subLevelBack.addSubview(self.subLevelScore)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.subLevelBack.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.bounds.size.width-20, self.bounds.size.height-20)
        self.subLevelLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, subLevelBack.frame.size.width/2-10, subLevelBack.frame.size.height)
        self.subLevelScore.frame = CGRectMake(subLevelBack.frame.size.width-120, 15, 100, subLevelBack.frame.size.height-30)
    }

}
```

Now I create these cells in my view controller as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:SubLevelTableCell? = SubLevelTable?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? SubLevelTableCell
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = SubLevelTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
                reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell!.backgroundColor = grayColor
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 0){nextLevelCanBePlayed = true}
        if(nextLevelCanBePlayed){
            canBePlayedArray[indexPath.row] = true
            cell!.subLevelBack.backgroundColor = blueColor
        }else{
            canBePlayedArray[indexPath.row] = false
            cell!.subLevelBack.backgroundColor = redColor
        }
        cell!.subLevelLabel.text = "Stage \(indexPath.row+1)"
        let data = db.query("SELECT * FROM LEVEL_DETAIL WHERE MAIN_LEVEL =\(MainLevelNr!) AND SUB_LEVEL = \(indexPath.row+1)")[0]
        var levelScore: Int = 0
        if let columnValue = data["COMPLETED"]{
            levelScore = columnValue.asInt()
            if (levelScore > 0){nextLevelCanBePlayed = true}else{nextLevelCanBePlayed = false}
            cell!.subLevelScore.image = UIImage(named: "\(levelScore)Stars.png")
        }
        return cell!
    }
```

My problem is that when the view loads for the first time, the `subLevelBack.backgroundColor` is set properly, ie. the subview's color is correct.

Though when I start scrolling, it becomes a bit of a mess with different cells having incorrect background colors, and I don't know how to solve this issue. I don't have this same issue with the image displayed in the UIImageView btw.

I hope someone will point me in the right direction. Kind regards, Sander

Comment: You don't need parens around your conditions: `if(nextLevelCanBePlayed){` should be `if nextLevelCanBePlayed {`.

Comment: Judging by your code, what should be the expected behavior for `sublevelBack.backgroundColor`? It will always be blue for the first cell and red for all other cells?

Comment: The parens are optional indeed, though I prefer to use them for readability. Actually, every row represents a level, and level n+1 can only be played (is blue) if level n is completed. The first level is always playable, and therefore indeed always blue. If a level is not playable the background is red. So, when row 1 is inserted I check whether level 1 is completed and than I set the bool nextLevelCanBePlayed accordingly. When row 2 is inserted it checks the bool value to determine its background color.

Comment: I see. Also, querying your db on every cell re-render is probably a performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (indexPath.row == 0){nextLevelCanBePlayed = true}
if(nextLevelCanBePlayed){ ...
```

The above code seems incorrect. You're trying to keep track of how many levels have been played, but each time the first cell gets re-rendered, `nextLevelCanBePlayed` will be reset. Perhaps try just `if(nextLevelCanBePlayed || indexPath.row == 0){`.

The other thing is you're making the assumption that the table view will re-render its cells near the viewport in order, but isn't documented anywhere and very likely isn't reliably true, and is especially likely if you're scrolling in the reverse direction. So when the table view re-builds cell 4 (`nextLevelCanBePlayed` calculates and sets to false) and maybe goes back to cell 3 next, and even if 3 is actually playable, `nextLevelCanBePlayed` will be false and 3 will show up incorrect. It then starts making sense that your colors start erratically changing as you scroll up and down.

My suggestion is to properly use your `UITableViewDataSource` methods and use those to work with the db and return proper data objects that represent the state and data of your cells.

Comment: Yes, I get your point, thanks. I will create an array of integers (levelScoreArray) in viewdidload and use this array as data source. So cell at indexpath i will use levelScoreArray[i] to set its color and image. This shoud do the trick I suppose. Cant fix it now unfortunately, but I will do it tonight and will accept you answer when it works! Thanks for now

Comment: Thnx, works like a charm now. bit of a stupid question i see now